# MySQL sort within a group with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I am attempting to work with the following tables:
users (id, name)
topics (id, name, slug)
posts (id, title, content, topicid, authorid, datetime, slug)
replies (id, authorid, threadid, content, datetime)

I want to create a list of posts ordered by latest reply (or the post date if there are no replies). Each listing should contain: the post title, the number of replies, the date of the post, the date of the latest reply, the name of the author, the name of the person who last replied, etc.

I can get everything except the date and author of the latest reply. The date can be done via MAX(replies.datetime), but I'm not sure how to get the latest author.

My last attempt was trying to use an exclusion join:

```
select posts.id, posts.title, posts.authorid, posts.topicid, posts.content, posts.datetime, count(replies.id) as replies, r2.datetime, replies.datetime, GREATEST(posts.datetime, coalesce(max(replies.datetime), posts.datetime)) as latesttime, users.name as author, commenters.name as commenter, r2.id 
from posts 
left join replies on replies.threadid = posts.id 
left join users on users.id = posts.authorid 
left join users commenters on commenters.id = replies.authorid
left join replies as r2 on replies.id = r2.id and replies.datetime < r2.datetime 
where r2.id is null 
group by posts.id 
order by latesttime DESC, replies.datetime DESC 
limit 20;
```

Unfortunately, this still won't retrieve the latest comment author. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first start with an inner most query on the max ID for a given thread and what it's REPLY ID was joined to the original replies to get ONE instance... From that, you can get the reply author's information.  THEN, get original posting information as needed.

```
SELECT 
      p.id,
      p.title,
      p.content,
      p.topicid,
      p.authorid,
      p.datetime as postdate,
      p.slug,
      postUser.Name as PostAuthor,
      coalesce( MaxReplyUser.NumReplies, 0 ) NumReplies,
      coalesce( MaxReplyUser.name, '' ) ReplyUser,
      coalesce( MaxReplyUser.AuthorID, 0 ) ReplyAuthor,
      coalesce( MaxReplyUser.ThreadID, 0 ) ReplyThread,
      coalesce( MaxReplyUser.DateTime, '' ) ReplyDateTime,
      coalesce( MaxReplyUser.Content, '' ) ReplyContent
   from 
      Posts p
         left join 
            ( SELECT 
                     u1.name,
                     r1.authorid,
                     r1.threadid,
                     r1.datetime,
                     r1.content,
                     MaxReplies.NumReplies
                  from 
                    ( SELECT 
                            threadid,
                            COUNT(*) as NumReplies,
                            MAX( id ) as MaxReplyID
                         from 
                            replies
                         group by 
                            threadID ) MaxReplies
                       INNER JOIN replies r1
                          ON MaxReplies.MaxReplyID = r1.id
                          INNER JOIN Users u1
                             ON r1.AuthorID = u1.ID ) MaxReplyUser
           ON p.id = MaxReplyUser.threadID
         inner join users postUser
            ON p.authorid = postuser.id
    order by 
       if( MaxReplyUser.threadID IS NULL, p.DateTime, MaxReplyUser.DateTime ) DESC
```

Comment: This works very well, although it looks like it might be a bit of a nightmare to implement with CodeIgniter's Active Record system! Is there a way to do it without the selects? (Also, newbie question: are selects any more or less efficient than joins?)

Comment: @RobL, The other solution by Joseadrian also appears to work, even with the bogus sample data I created to test my version... it too has SELECTS embedded as columns, but either way has selects.

Comment: Just tested it myself and indeed it does work! Again, a bit wary of the selects. Thanks for your help with this!

Answer (score 1):

uld you test it?

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.title, posts.authorid, posts.topicid, posts.content, posts.datetime, 
(SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = posts.autorid) "Author",
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM replies WHERE threadid = posts.id) "Replies",
(SELECT MAX(datetime) FROM replies r WHERE threadid = posts.id) "Lastreplytime",
(SELECT (SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = r.authorid LIMIT 1) FROM replies r WHERE threadid = posts.id ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1)
FROM posts 
ORDER BY Lastreplytime DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: As DRapp notes above, this version also works. I'm slightly wary of the sheer number of select statements here, but I have no idea if this is more or less efficient than using joins.

Comment: I was trying with more than 20 JOINS on a query for a project. This query had group by order by etc... and it was slower than making subqueries. It took one minute to get more than 5000 results, and with A LOT of subqueries took 2 o 3 seconds :x

Comment: Well, I hope to avoid having as many as twenty joins or subqueries! Thanks for the tip though - will bear it in mind!